# Put link on img / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put link on every img. pls help !

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
myimages[1]="noveslike/bg1.jpg"
myimages[2]="noveslike/bg2.jpg"
myimages[3]="noveslike/bg3.jpg"

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please use google translator

Comment: Why the Lorem Ipsum? And why do you not just add an anchor tag around your image?

Comment: @pilot lol that's not something for us. Its garbage data. Just google Lorem Ipsum..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Just add a new object to the 'myimages' array for a new image, example:

```
myimages[x] = { src: "imageSource", link: "http://..." };
```

It's also better this way, because it's easier to maintain relations between images and links.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
myimages[1]= { src: "noveslike/bg1.jpg", link: "http://www.google.com" };
myimages[2]= { src: "noveslike/bg2.jpg", link: "http://www.youtube.com" };
myimages[3]= { src: "noveslike/bg3.jpg", link: "http://www.facebook.com" };

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
image = myimages[ry];

document.write('<a href="' + image.link + '"><img src="'+ image.src +'" border=0></a>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Tnx men you help me a lot !

Comment: Do you know how to put target (_self,_top...) ?

Comment: Change <a href="' + image.link + '"> to <a href="' + image.link + '" target="_self">

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
document.write('<a href="' + myImages[ry] + '"><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0></a>');
```

I assume you want to make a link to the image you're showing.

Comment: By the way, your code is a bit obsolete. Nobody uses document.write nowadays, and the 'border' attribute in images is deprecated, you should learn to use CSS if you're learning, ant it seems you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
if (ry==0)
ry=1
   document.write('<a href="'+URL+'"><img src="'+myimages[ry]+'"></a>')
}
```